# What's meaning of "I KNOW FFS THANKS SOO MUCH , exucse my language"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, abbreviations

There is a question on Server Fault: [Job for httpd.service failed](https://serverfault.com/questions/686825/job-for-httpd-service-failed). Here is the answer and a comment.

**Answer**:

> The key error message appears to be:
>
> > `SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/httpd/ssl/apache.srt' does not exist or is empty`
>
> Which is likely a small typo in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` in the name of the SSL public key component of your certificate, most likely it should be apache.**c**rt instead of apache.**s**rt

You can see the comment under the answer.
**Comment**:

> I KNOW FFS THANKS SOO MUCH , exucse my language

What mean of the "I know FFS"?
And "exucse my language"?

Comment: Thanks, but please consider [waiting longer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) before accepting.

Comment: @Max why? I think I can understand now.

Comment: There are many benefits (see the link). Waiting longer is a good habit because it gives others a chance to review answers, in case there are any errors. That's my main concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the best way to punctuate this, but here is one way:

> I know, FFS! Thanks so much! Excuse my language.

I'm not entirely sure what the *I know* does here, but I think it's simply an expression of agreement:

> [I know](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/i-know)
>   said to show you agree with something someone has just said:
>   *"But he's so awful." "I know - he's dreadful."*
>   (Cambridge Dictionary)

*FFS* stands for *for fuck's sake*. It's an expression of frustration.

> [for fuck's sake](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+fuck%27s+sake)
>   rude slang An expression of annoyance or frustration at what someone is doing or at a situation that is unfolding. *Oh, for fuck's sake, Chris—you know I wasn't trying to hurt you, so stop acting like a wounded puppy. Stop playing your music so loud, for fuck's sake!*
>   (TFD)

I don't know much about the topic, but it seems like he's frustrated that such a small error caused him such a huge headache.

*Excuse my language* just means that he's asking the respondent to excuse his usage of profanity.